# Adding data from Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a view of some blog post with option to add comments using a partial view.

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Comments")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

My Details view is also quite simple:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Model.Data.Post>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

    <div>
        <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id) %>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Text) %>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Text) %>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div id="Comments">
    <%: Html.Partial("_CreateComment", new Model.Data.Comment() )%>
</div>
```

Now the interesting part, the Partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Model.Data.Comment>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Comment</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

In my controller I have a method for handling the new comment:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Comment comment)
{
    comment.AddedOn = DateTime.Now;
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

But for some reason my new comment `Id` is set to be the same as the `Id` of the `Post` from the parent view. How do I make the `Post.Id` to be mapped to `Comment.PostId` instead of `Comment.Id`?

## Update

My guess is that it takes the value from routing path to the controller, which is {controller}/{action}/{id} could it be? is there anyway to prevent it from happening? I tried to add an `id` argument to the method, but it still maps the inner `Id` of the comment not only the argument itself...

Comment: Try `Html.Partial("_CreateComment", new Model.Data.Comment() { PostId = Model.Id })` and then create a hidden input for `PostId` so it posts back

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, this helped, but only partially, now I have both fields contain the same value?

Comment: That probably because the you have the standard route with `../../{id}` so the ID from `Post` is being passed with the ViewDataDictionary and added to the route (inspect the html generated for the `form` tag and you will probably see `action="/../Details/#` where `#` is the `PostId`) . You could add a hidden input for `Id` as well which should post back the default value `0` or just ignore it in the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you post an answer on this? Also please add a few words on what do you mean by "just ignore it in the controller".

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried to add a hidden Id, which had to get its value from the model initializer `new Model.Data.Comment() { Id = 0, PostId = Model.Id }` but the model that gets to the view already contains the id from route..

Comment: By _ignore_  I meant to set `comment.Id = 0;` before saving. Personally I would be using a view model and just rendering everything in the main view (no partial). But another option is to have a child action that accepts the `PostId`, initializes a new `Comment` with the `PostId` and returns a partial view for the `Comment`, then in the main view `@Html.Action("..", new { id = Model.PostId })`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How should I add an option to add a `Comment` if my view is based on `Post` without using the partial view?

Comment: By using a view model which contains a property (say) `public Comment Comment { get set; }` and posting back to a method with `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="Comment")]Comment model)`, but I would probably post using ajax anyway (assuming you wanted to stay on the same page)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would you add an answer summarizing all your suggestions, so I can accept it? Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: I have just given you some options to consider. It would be better for you to add an answer with what worked for you and then accept it :)